# Why am I getting search traffic for a page even though its ranking is very low?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

As per Google Search Console, a certain page on my website has a ranking of ~50 yet it's getting increasingly more organic traffic. For example, today it had about 10 unique visits from Google. How is this possible when the ranking is so low and hasn't changed much in the past 1 month? Could it be that google experimenting with my ranking by sending some traffic my way?

Comment: Is your search console linked to Analytics? Because that would give you access to more information about that traffic. My first thoughts would be that it was either very long keywords, it's possibly Google Images searches, or it's bots.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!! Some searches are not users, they are machines accessing search APIs. Many of these searches are used to measure the results for SEO sites. Some are used by spammers and junk web sites that create links. You will see searches often for popular terms and searches in Search Console or Analytics. I cannot say this is what you are seeing without perhaps a screen shot. Many people do not realize this practice happens. Just thought you may want to know. Cheers!!